# What is echostr in Lbank api?

Tags: php, rest, exchange-server

I want use Lbank api in php language. What is `echostr`?

According to Lbank docs: https://docs.lbkex.net/en/#authentication

> `echostr`: the param is digit or letter，length is from 30 to 40. You can directly use echostr of SDK, it's safe.

How can I create `echostr` in php?

Comment: According to [this sample code](https://github.com/LBank-exchange/lbank-api-sdk-v2/blob/28cbe43c7d48f8d973f8495784ef71cedeab2f2f/lbank-python-sdk-api/LBank/client.py#L43), it is just a random string

Comment: yes, it's true
thanks